# R - Remove consecutive values from dataset, subject to condition of second variable

Tags: r

Suppose we have a dataset with a `days` variable and a `condition` variable. I want to remove rows that have `condition==F`, only if they appear consecutively and the corresponding entries for `days` sum to over 180.

Here is example code:

```
data <- data.frame(days = c(0, 30, 60, 60, 70, 60, 40, 30, 30, 30, 30), 
                   condition = c(F, T, F, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F))

> data
  days condition
1     0     FALSE
2    30      TRUE
3    60     FALSE
4    60     FALSE
5    70     FALSE
6    60      TRUE
7    40     FALSE
8    30      TRUE
9    30     FALSE
10   30     FALSE
11   30     FALSE
```

I would want to remove rows 3,4,5, but not rows 9,10,11 (since the `days` don't sum to over 180 in this case). Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by the run-length-id of 'condition', we check the condition if the `sum` of 'days' is less than 180 and the 'condition' is FALSE or (`|`), the TRUE values, get the column of index and subset the data

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data[,  (sum(days) < 180) & !condition |condition, .(grp = rleid(condition))]$V1]
#   days condition
#1:    0     FALSE
#2:   30      TRUE
#3:   60      TRUE
#4:   40     FALSE
#5:   30      TRUE
#6:   30     FALSE
#7:   30     FALSE
#8:   30     FALSE
```

Comment: Should probably not ask here but is there any benefit from using `setDT` over `as.data.table`?

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! One more thing that I didn't originally ask, but... how would you extract the row numbers that get deleted (i.e., 3.4.5)?

Comment: @KirkFogg  Thanks, you can use the `.I` i.e. `setDT(data)[,  .I[!((sum(days) < 180) & !condition |condition)], .(grp = rleid(condition))]$V1#
[1] 3 4 5`

Comment: I think I answered my own question. The deleted row numbers correspond to the FALSE entries in the code within the bracket (EDIT: But akrun's answer above mine is better)

Comment: @Yannis The `set` functions are a bit fast but it also depends whether you need to change the orignal dataset or not.  `setDT` changes the original object to data.table while `as.data.table` you need to assign it to the same object or different object